# Send Output Of OracleOperator To Another Task In Airflow

Tags: airflow

I need to use the output from oracleOperator in another task for further execution. The trouble I have is that when I pull the data into another task and print it, it gives a result as None. There is no error thrown but the data isn't passed through. Also, the **xcom** tab in task UI shows blank for keys and values.

My code is as follows:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.oracle_operator import OracleOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
    'owner': 'xyz',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG('example_xcom', schedule_interval="@once", default_args=args, tags=['example'])


def puller(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    # get value_1
    pulled_value_1 = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='push')
    print("VALUE IN PULLER ")
    print(pulled_value_1)

pull = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pullee',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=puller,
    provide_context=True,
)
push = OracleOperator(
    task_id='data',
    sql='SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS', 
    oracle_conn_id='1',
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)


push>>pull
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code. Basically using `PythonOperator` with `OracleHook`.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks.oracle_hook import OracleHook
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
    'owner': 'xyz',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG('example_xcom', schedule_interval="@once", default_args=args, tags=['example'])


def puller(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    # get value_1
    pulled_value_1 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='data')
    print("VALUE IN PULLER : ", pulled_value_1)


def get_data_from_oracle(**kwargs):
    oracle_hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=kwargs['oracle_conn_id'])
    return oracle_hook.get_records(sql=kwargs['sql'])

push = PythonOperator(
    task_id='data',
    op_kwargs={'oracle_conn_id': 'oracle_conn_id', 'sql': 'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS'}
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_data_from_oracle,
    dag=dag,
)

pull = PythonOperator(
    task_id='pullee',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=puller,
    provide_context=True,
)


push >> pull
```

Comment: Hi. The value is being pushed into xcom in the push call and i can see it in the logs, but i am still unable to pull the data in the puller function. It prints the value as 'None'; i.e. 'pulled_value_1' is printed as 'None'

Comment: @MrSir Updated the code, try now. Basically remove `key=None` from xcom_pull

Comment: Still couldn't get it in the puller function, it still prints it as None. Also, the puller task's XCOM parameter doesn't have the values; but the pusher task's does.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have updated the answer (needed to update `task_ids` in `xcom_pull`) and this time tested it on my machine too.

Answer (score 0):

Your DAG seems to be fine here. However, looking into the source code of [airflow.operators.oracle_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/oracle_operator.html), you may realize that the main execute method is actually using `OracleHook()` apart of [airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook/index.html#airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook.DbApiHook.get_records) module extensions:

```
def execute(self, context):
  self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)
  hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id=self.oracle_conn_id)
  hook.run(
      self.sql,
      autocommit=self.autocommit,
      parameters=self.parameters)
```

And the culprit here is `hook.run()` method that runs SQL query but returns nothing to the Xcom, thus `xcom_pull()` method retrieves none records.

> **run(self, sql, autocommit=False, parameters=None)[source]**
>
> Runs a command or a list of commands. Pass a list of sql statements to the
>   sql parameter to get them to execute sequentially

As a solution, you can create custom Airflow [Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) duplicating source code of genuine `OracleOperator()` and replacing `hook.run()` with [hook.get_records()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook/index.html#airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook.DbApiHook.get_records) method, then you will expect to execute the nested query, fetching resulting records for further pushing to the next task.

Hope you find this useful.